# How do I create an user_id for a FactoryGirl build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm new to FactoryGirl, Faker, and more broadly testing.

I believe I need to add an ID to my user that is created by FactoryGirl in order to assess whether the user can access certain pages and/or has ownership over certain nested resources. I'm questioning this because as I do research(Google and check StackOverflow) I'm not seeing a lot of information about generating IDs for FactoryGirl created resources. Since my user comes with an ID of nil I assume the FactoryGirl default is to build a resource without adding an ID.

I do see information about creating associations, but even those seem to be absent ids. In the app I'm creating all access to a user's resources are checked against a user's ID.

Should I be creating and ID for my FactoryGirl generated users?
If not, why not? What should I do instead?
If so, how do I generate different user IDs to check against each other?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID should be assigned/incremented automatically if you are persisting the user object. It's possible you're using `build` to instantiate the object rather than `create`.

`user = build(:user)` <-- Object is created, not saved, no ID

`user = create(:user)` <--- Object is created and saved, has ID

For best practices, ensure your tests are run on a separate database so that you don't pollute your live data. You could also check out https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner  for an easy way to clean up your test data after a test has been run.

Comment: Thanks, this makes so much sense I don't know how I missed it before now.